# Android Periodic Background Services

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-intentservice

I have a doubt that if i start a periodic service using alarm manager and start the service from the onCreate method of an activity. How can i prevent the service from triggering multiple times if that activity is launched again and again.

Comment: can you show the code?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are creating a Normal `Service` (and not an `IntentService`), as per the Android `Service` [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService(android.content.Intent)), when app invokes `startService` call,  service will be instantiated and started (creating a process for it if needed).

Also, if it is running then it remains running.

So, to put it in simple terms,

> Life cycle of "Started" service  is independent of the life cycle of
>   Activity which has started this service. This is true irrespective
>   weather both are running in same process or different processes

So even though your `Activity` may be getting created multiple times, and if `Service` you created earlier is still running, then service object that already exists will be reused.

However, if there is a call to `startService()` from `onCreate()` of an `Activity`, this will invoke each time `onStartCommand()`.

Hence, you need to ensure that you have a appropriate code/logic to handle multiple invocations of `onStartCommand()`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you must do something in either onCreate/onStart and onStop or onResume and onPaused. By do something I mean, in onCreate create what you need, alarm manager, etc then in onStart you can start the service and in onStop you stop the service or unBind from it, in case you want a foreground service. or in onResume or onStop.
Take a look here:

https://github.com/toaderandrei/live_tracking/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/ant/track/activities/ServiceConnectActivity.java.
It is a tracking app that is based on MyTracks app from google.